# How to merge to object and replace the empty value to new value and if new value is empty keep the old value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

i having an array of object each time I select a value I am pushing it into an array, I want to merge the two objects having a same key ie key "code", and remove the empty value

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {code: "abc", value: "", access: "A"}
1: {code: "abc", value: "ok", access: ""}
2: {code: "def", value: "xyz", access: ""}
3: {code: "def", value: "", access: "B"}

the output should be
(2) [{…},{…}]
0: { code: "abc", value: "ok", access: "A"}
1: {code: "def", value: "xyz", access: "B"}
```

I have tried with spread operator but its not working. please help me out

Comment: May you share the code you used?

Comment: Where did the `id` property in the output come from ?

Comment: @Titus sorry updated

Comment: please describe more why did you merged 0 and 1 ,is there any relationship with `code`?
Where did the id property comes from?

Comment: its merged based on the code, if the code is equal it should be merged

Comment: The merge by default updates the value from the target into the source, so using `{...[0],...[1]}` or `Object.assign({},[0],[1])`, always replaces value from [1] for the matching properties, for your case, you have to skip the property having empty or null or undefined or use custom merge logic

Comment: you could simply use a library like lodash like https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.reduce(..)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) here is an example:

```js
const input = [
  {code: "abc", value: "", access: "A"},
  {code: "abc", value: "ok", access: ""},
  {code: "def", value: "xyz", access: ""},
  {code: "def", value: "", access: "B"}
];

const output = input.reduce((a, c) => {
  const found = a.find(({ code }) => c.code === code);
  if (found) {
    Object.entries(c).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (!found[key]) {
        found[key] = value;
      }
    });
  } else {
    a.push(c);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Even though this works correctly for the example input it will fail in some cases because it replaces all **falsy** values (the boolean value `false` the number `0`, etc.) which may not be your intent.

To prevent that, replace the `!found[key]` condition in the `if` statement with whatever check fits your needs.